# Do not unsubscribe from COMObject events can cause memory leak although I use Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject?

Tags: c#, memory, com, memory-leaks

Do not unsubscribe from COMObject events can cause memory leak although I use Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject?

I have defined new member in my class that is COMObject

```
protected COMObject.Call call_ = null;
```

This class has the following event handlers that I subscribed to

```
call_.ActionA += new COMObject.AEventHandler(AEvent);
call_.ActionB += new COMObject.BEventHandler(BEvent);
call_.Destructed += new COMObject.DestructedEventHandler(CallDestructedEvent);
```

When the Destructed event is called I do Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject

```
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(call_)
```

but not unsubscribe from the events

```
call_.ActionA -= new COMObject.AEventHandler(AEvent);
call_.ActionB -= new COMObject.BEventHandler(BEvent);
call_.Destructed -= new COMObject.DestructedEventHandler(CallDestructedEvent);
```

Is this can cause memory leak? or that the GC will handle it?
Can you link your answer to some MSDN or article?

Thanks! Dor.

Comment: Randomly guessing at the causes of memory leaks is rarely the right way to do things. There are a number of tools (some free, some paid) that could help you try to find the source of the leak. You'd do better finding and using those.

Comment: Can you recommend on one? that could handle COM and .Net?

Comment: I'd start with using the "Debugging Tools for Windows", specifically ADPlus, to capture a memory dump (either, hopefully, when an OutOfMemoryException occurs, or just after some prolonged usage). WinDBG can then be used to explore that memory dump. An extension called SOS can be loaded, which then allows you to examine the same dump from a .NET perspective. I'd go and read up on these before you attempt using them though (they're not for the faint hearted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried unsubscribing them before doing the release to see if it helps the memory leak?
You've got a destructed handler, you could do it in there.

Do you ever call any of the properties of the COM object, and if you do, [have you released them properly too?](http://forums.asp.net/t/1735441.aspx/1)
I think that even if you call FinalReleaseComObject on the parent object, if you haven't released the child objects too then even though there are no reference to the parent there may still be references to the children hanging about.

Comment: Can you supply link to support your Answer?

Comment: Apart from the link I included in my original answer, there's this: http://mvdeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/02/marshalfinalreleasecomobject-fun.html but neither of them address memory leaks specifically. If you're running this same code repeatedly and the COM object is not single instance then you're going to get multiple copies of the COM object building up in memory.

Comment: Also, within your event handlers, if you're using any properties of the COM object you need to make sure you release them in the handler as well.